# Select records with fallback check MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a `SELECT` query which gives me some `projects and clients` from my database.

My initial query is at follows:

```
SELECT p.id, p.name as projectName, c.name as clientName, p.rate 
        FROM Project p, Client c
        WHERE p.client_id = c.id AND p.name NOT LIKE "%leave" AND p.hidden != 1
        ORDER BY c.name ASC, p.name ASC
```

As you can see if a project has the `hidden` column as `1 (true) then I don't want to show it.

Now I have added this `hidden column` also on `Clients table`. This is because if a client `is hidden` then I don't want to show the projects that are assigned to it.

How should I transform my `query` if a project has `hidden = 0` to check if the client has `hidden = 1` and don't show it.

I tried something like this:

```
SELECT p.id, p.name as projectName, c.name as clientName, p.rate 
        FROM Project p, Client c
        WHERE p.client_id = c.id AND p.name NOT LIKE "%leave" AND (c.hidden != 1 OR p.hidden != 1)
        ORDER BY c.name ASC, p.name ASC
```

I guess is something like a fallback, if `project.hidden = 0` also check for `client.hidden` and if `client.hidden = 1` then don't show the record, but if the `client.hidden = 0` then show the record.

Here are my tables:

**Client**

[image]

**Project**

[image]

### Update with dummy data

Let's say these are my clients:

[image]

And these are the projects:

[image]

In the end I need the get the projects that neither them or the client that are assigned to them are not hidden: `Project X, Project Z, Project W and Project B`.

Because the other project are either `hidden` or the `client which is assigned to them is hidden`.

### Solution

I went so far for a simple answer. Here is the solution:

```
SELECT p.id, p.name as projectName, c.name as clientName, p.rate 
            FROM Project p, Client c
            WHERE p.client_id = c.id AND p.name NOT LIKE "%leave" AND c.hidden != 1 AND p.hidden != 1
            ORDER BY c.name ASC, p.name ASC
```

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you want to do is show the project when the project and the client are not hidding,you can just do c.hidden = 0 and p.hidden = 0.

Comment: Of course, i went so far away from the answer but it was so simple. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

use join and where like below

```
     SELECT p.id, p.name as projectName, 
     c.name as clientName, p.rate 
    FROM Project p join Client c
    on p.client_id = c.id
   where  p.name NOT LIKE "%leave" 
   AND p.hidden = 0 and c.hidden=0
    ORDER BY c.name ASC, p.name ASC
```

Comment: But this query will just get my projects that are not hidden, but the client that is assigned to them is hidden. I want if the client is hidden to not get any projects from it or if the project itself is hidden to not get it

Comment: @poPaTheGuru share sample data and expected result

Comment: I have added some dummy initial data with expected result

Comment: @poPaTheGuru why Project B in outcome?

Comment: because the project B is not hidden and the client that is assigned to it is not hidden too.